# Python program not being started by rc.d in FreeBSD 7.1

Tags: freebsd, python

I have a python program which I wrote and would like to run on startup in FreeBSD 7.1.

For my current installation, the script lives at
`/home/devuser/project/trunk/src/proj`. At the beginning of my `main` in `proj` I have added (for testing)

```
os.system("echo 'proj STARTED' >> /tmp/projlog")
```

In /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ I have 'proj' which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
# PROVIDE: proj
# REQUIRE: DAEMON LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown
. "/etc/rc.subr"

$location="/home/devuser/project/trunk/src"

name="proj"
rcvar=`set_rcvar`
command="$location/$name"
command_args="$1"
command_interpreter="python"

load_rc_config $name
echo "trying to run proj" >> /tmp/rclog
run_rc_command "$1"
```

In my rc.conf:

```
rc_debug="YES"
proj_enable="YES"
```

If I run `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/proj <start|stop|status>` as `root` everything works as expected - `proj` runs, `trying to run proj` appears in `/tmp/rclog`, and `proj STARTED` appears in `/tmp/projlog`.

On system startup, I get `trying to run proj` in `/tmp/rclog`, but nothing in `/tmp/projlog` - python isn't being started.

Why is the rc script running but failing to actually invoke Python, and not giving me any feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing **/usr/local/bin** (or wherever the python binary resides in FreeBSD) doesn't exist in `$PATH` when running init scripts.

Try changing `command_interpreter="python"` to `command_interpreter="/usr/local/bin/python"`.

Also, does the your file contain a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (with a correct path) and is executable?

Comment: Specifying the full interpreter path fixed it.

Also, `proj contained a shebang and correct path, but opened several subprocesses using `Popen`, which specified `#!/usr/bin/env python` - rc didn't like this. Using `#!/usr/local/bin/python` instead has made everything start working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that python is in the path on boot up.

Try specifying the full path in your command_interpreter variable.